# How to Hide/Change name Processes called in Bash Script from ps

Tags: linux, bash, process, hide

I'm new to bash scripting, writing a bash to do some commands,
sample:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
var2=$2
var3="$(~/ourCcompiledprogram -c check -v error -f syn)"

$var3 $var1 $var2
```

when we run the bash script it works very well,
but the problem is if someone, login to server and exec ps aux, top, htop and so on ...
will see the process running like this: /home/user/ourCcompiledprogram -c check -v error -f force ~/input.file ~/output.file

how to prevent this ? or what to add to the bash script to run all the external commands called in bash as a specified name !?

Comment: This  [\[ laborious method \]](https://sysdig.com/blog/hiding-linux-processes-for-fun-and-profit)  describes how to achieve this. Do have a look at [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775287/writing-a-program-for-hiding-processes-from-ps-command-result) and [\[ these \]](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[linux]+hide+a+process) similar SO questions.

Comment: @sjsam did u read all the sysdig article ? " In fact, sysdig can see everything "

Comment: Read the question title once more. I didn't assume that `sysdig` too is installed in your environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux provides information about running processes in a variety of places in the `/proc` filesystem. Most of these are hard to spoof, without a lot of work. In general, you would have to modify the system execution environment, and even then you might not be able to hide the information completely.

In a comment, [@sjsam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1620779/sjsam) provides [a link to an article](https://sysdig.com/blog/hiding-linux-processes-for-fun-and-profit) which shows how to use the preload mechanism to intercept calls which would open the `/proc` filesystem, and use that to hide information about specific processes. However, as that article also points out, there are other mechanisms for acquiring process information.

There are four `/proc` entries which hold relevant information: (In all the following, `PID` should be replaced with the numeric PID of the process.)

- `/proc/PID/cmdline`: This is the easiest to spoof, since it shows the `argv` array (or, more accurately, the first 4,096 bytes of the `argv` array), in which `argv[0]` is presented as the command name. With the bash `exec` built-in, you can provide anything you want as the value of `argv[0]` using the `-a` flag. (This is a bash extension. It may not be present in other shells.) So you could simply use:

  ```
  exec -a SpoofedName RealCommandName arg...
  ```

  Since this is the default source of information for `ps`, it will hide the command name (but not the arguments) from a casual use of `ps`.
- `/proc/PID/stat` and `/proc/PID/status`: These show status information for `PID`; the first one is in a format easy for programs to parse, and the second one in a format easier for human beings to read. Both show the actual filename of the process executable. This is the source of information for the `comm` selector in `ps`, and also for the process name in `top`.

  You can spoof this name by creating a symlink to the executable, and executing the symlink instead of the original file. That will take care of `ps -ocomm` and `top`
- `/proc/PID/exe`: This is a symlink to the actual executable. I don't believe there is a simple way of spoofing this value, other than actually copying the executable to a new file and executing that file (which is not really a spoof). However, as far as I know, it is not used by any command-line utility which shows process information. The user would need to type something like:

  ```
  ls -ld /proc/8325/exe
  ```

  or

  ```
  readlink /proc/8325/exe
  ```

  to see the filename of the executable.